# Nodejs lambda function timing out

Tags: mysql, node.js, aws-lambda

Just trying out Lambda and nodejs.
I have a timeout error that happens every few times.

My nodejs code is below.

```
var mysql = require('mysql');

var pool = mysql.createPool({
  connectionLimit: 100,
  host     : 'hostname',
  user     : 'username',
  password : 'password',
  database : 'database',
  port : 3306
});


exports.handler = async (event, context, callback) => {
    let request = JSON.parse(event.body);
    let sId = request.sid;
    let questionnaireId = request.questionnaireId;

    pool.getConnection((error, connection) => {
        if (error) throw error;
        let sql = "INSERT INTO answers (qId, sId,) VALUES(" + questionnaireId + ", " + sid + ")";
        connection.query(sql, function(err, result){
            if(err) throw err;
            console.log("Successfull Insert")
            connection.release();
        });

    });

    const response = {
        statusCode: 200,
        headers: {
                    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
                    'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': true
                },
        body: JSON.stringify({message : 'success'}),
    };

    return response;
};
```

Cloudwatch shows the below message.

> "errorMessage": "connect ETIMEDOUT",
>       "code": "ETIMEDOUT",

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing `callback` argument from your handler. You are returning a promise from your function, so you don't need it.

Defining `callback` as an argument probably makes aws think you are gonna call it when your function finishes executing, and as you don't it produces a timeout error.

Comment: Declaring the handler async was it for me. I had returned, but didn't mark the function as async and it timed out every time. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
return response;
```

with this:

```
callback(null, response)
```

Reference: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-prog-model-handler.html